# How not to plot all points of geom_jitter?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have another question about geom_boxplot.
Is it posible not to plot geom_jitter for outliers? Like this I can have outliers in one color and jitter points in another

```
aa <- c(rep("A1",5), rep("A2",3), rep("A3",4), rep("A4",9), rep("A5",3))
aa <- as.factor(aa)
per <- runif(length(aa), min=0, max=100)
per <- trunc(per)
z <- data.frame(x=aa,y=per)
z$ch <- NA
z[z$x %in% c("A1","A2"), "ch"] <- "string1"
z[z$x %in% c("A3"), "ch"] <- "string2"
z[z$x %in% c("A4", "A5"), "ch"] <- "string3"

z$ch <- as.factor(z$ch)
z$x = with(z, factor(x, rev(levels(x))))
p <- ggplot(z, aes(x, y, fill = ch)) + 
 geom_boxplot(size = 0.2, position = "dodge", outlier.colour = "red", outlier.shape = 16,      outlier.size = 2) + 
geom_jitter(size=1,position = "dodge") + 
opts(legend.position = "right") + 
scale_colour_hue("variable") +
coord_flip()
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a column `is.outlier` to your dataset `z` (which is `TRUE` if and only if that value is an outlier).  If you want to do something to everything but the outliers, include a data argument with the non-outlier subset, e.g.,

```
geom_jitter(some_stuff, data = subset(z, !is.outlier))
```

Do do different things to outliers and non-outliers, use `is.outlier` in your aesthetic, e.g.,

```
geom_point(aes(size = is.outlier + 1))
```

Comment: I understand the idea but I didn't succeed to realize  this. outlier points is for string 1 or 2 or 3 and not for each lines. So I don't understand how can I add is.outlier column to my data frame. Also, is.outlier is for objects class modlist...

Comment: I must confess I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.  `geom_jitter` is adding jittered points to the plot.  They aren't outliers.